# ¿Cómo utilizar una biblioteca de jquery que está en node_modules en un componente de Angular?

Tags: angular

Tengo instalado el paquete de masonry y sus archivos están en `node_modules/masonry_layout`. También tengo instalado jQuery. Necesito utilizar Masonry en un componente.

En mi componente tengo lo siguiente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';window["$"] = $; window["jQuery"] = $;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-galeria',
  templateUrl: './galeria.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./galeria.component.min.css']
})
export class GaleriaComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        percentPosition: true
      });
    });
  }
}
```

He intentado importar Masonry al componente de las siguientes maneras:

```
import * as _ from ‘masonry-layout’;
import * from ‘masonry-layout’;
import 'node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.min.js';
```

También intenté guardar el `masonry.min.js` en mi directorio de `assets` y cargarlo directamente en `index.html` como un script cualquiera.

```
<script src="node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.min.js"></script>
```

Nada de esto ha funcionado. La consola me dice que la función `masonry()` no es una propiedad de jQuery.

¿Saben cómo cargar correctamente este tipo de archivos a los componentes?

Comment: te da algun error en la consola? en que orden cargas los scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación de Masonry puedes usar el plugin sin jQuery lo primero que debes hacer es instalar masonry desde npm

```
npm install masonry-layout --save
```

y para usar el plugin solo necesitas hacer el import de esta manera

```
import  Masonry  from 'masonry-layout';
```

en el componente que desees usar, te pongo un ejemplo ya funcionando https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dz1sva

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. En el demo que enlazas puedo hacerlo funcionar perfectamente a como lo necesito (Utilizando imágenes), pero en mi proyecto me tira el siguiente error. `masonry_layout_1.default is not a constructor` esto utilizando el método del `new Masonry`. Utilizando el método de jQuery me sale `$(...).masonry is not a function`.  Intenté con `declare var masonry: any;` pero sigue el error.

Comment: he creado un proyecto en local y he probado el ejemplo que te proporcione y me funciona correctamente, verifica que tengas instalada la librería, puedes probar desinstalando la librería y volver a instalarla

Comment: ¿Podrías decirme qué paquetes de node instalaste? Yo tengo instalado jquery y masonry-layout --save

Comment: cree un nuevo proyecto desde 0 con y solo instale masonry, de la manera como lo puse en mi respuesta

Comment: Igual acabo de crear un proyecto desde 0 pero sigue igual.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

**1**. En tu archivo index.html debes tener declarado tu archivo jquery.min: 

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

**2**. Instalar con `npm install masonry-layout --save`

**3**. Abrir el archivo .angular-cli.json (se encuentra en la raiz de tu proyecto)

**4**. Ir a la parte "scripts"

`"scripts": [
          "../node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"
      ],`

**5**. En tu componente debe quedar de la siguiente manera

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:any;
declare var Masonry: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-galeria',
  templateUrl: './galeria.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./galeria.component.min.css']
})
export class GaleriaComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        percentPosition: true
      });
    });

    // o puede hacerlo de esta manera
    /*
  var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
  var msnry = new Masonry( elem, {
    // options
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 200
  })
    */
  }
}
```

**6**. Si sigues con problemas, puedes revisar este repositorio de masonry compatible con angular, el github es: [Click aquí](https://github.com/jelgblad/angular2-masonry)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El método que pones no me funciona, me sale `$(...).masonry is not a function` en la consola. Chequé el repositorio de github pero tampoco funcionaba en mi proyecto.